# Autofill multi dimensional String[][] array

Tags: java, arrays, string

I have a String array:

```
String[][] array = new String[7][6];
```

And I want to auto-fill everything with `"[]"`, with one loop to basically set a default value. I tried to use `Arrays.fill` but it didn't work out well.

Comment: Anything wrong with using two nested loops?

Comment: I dont know how to set the condition for the max. lenght of the loop in a multidimensional array and then actually set the value to "[ ]".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Arrays.asList(array).forEach(a->Arrays.fill(a,"[]"));
```

Comment: That one looks pretty good, thanks.
Could you maybe explain what that forEach exactly do?

Comment: @DeanJ. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html#forEach-java.util.function.Consumer-

Answer (score 0):

This will work for you if you want it in one loop.

```
String[][] myArray = new String[7][6];
int i, j;
for(i=0; i<7; i++)
{
j=i;
myArray[i] [j]= " ";
j++;
myArray[i] [j]= " ";
j++;
myArray[i] [j]= " ";
j++;
myArray[i] [j]= " ";
j++;
myArray[i] [j]= " ";
j++;
myArray[i] [j]= " ";
}
```